# Questions on Joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

TransactionList (id is not unique) e.g., Transaction 1 has item 1 (apple) with quantity = 1

| id | item | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

ItemList

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |
| 3 | Orange |

How can I join the above two tables and get the following expected result?
Expected Result (include all possible items in all transaction and the corresponding value):

| id | item | quantity | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Apple |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | Banana |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | Orange |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | Apple |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Banana |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | Orange |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Apple |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | Banana |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | Orange |

I cannot get my head around on this question. Not sure if cross join is useful in my case.

Comment: Presumably you have a `Transaction` table too?

Comment: If `id` in not unique, please call it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is with a CROSS JOIN and conditional aggration:

```
SELECT 
     t.id
    ,i.id
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.item = i.id THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS quantity
    ,i.name
FROM dbo.ItemList AS i
CROSS JOIN dbo.TransactionList AS t
GROUP BY 
     t.id
    ,i.id
    ,i.name
ORDER BY 
     t.id
    ,i.id;
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, Dan.

Comment: @cyyung, please mark this as the answer to provide visibility to others with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TRANSACTIONS(id,   item,   quantity) AS
(  
    SELECT 1,   1,  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   1,  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   2,  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   3,  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,   1,  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,   2,  1 
),
ITEM_LIST(id,name) AS
(
   SELECT  1,   'Apple' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,    'Banana'UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,    'Orange'
),
ALL_PERMUTATIONS AS
(
  SELECT T.ID,X.ID AS ITEM,0 AS COUNTT,X.name
  FROM TRANSACTIONS T
  CROSS JOIN ITEM_LIST X
)
SELECT A.ID,A.ITEM,ISNULL(T.quantity,A.COUNTT)AS QUANTITY,A.NAME
FROM ALL_PERMUTATIONS AS A
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS AS T ON A.ID=T.ID AND A.ITEM=T.item
ORDER BY A.ID
```

I guess, you can try something like this